# Radius of equal circles within a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

If an outside circle has a known radius `R`, and I want to fit `n` equal circles inside of it, what would the radius of each of those circles `r` be?

I've found this answer which I think shows how to do this for `n`=3, but I'm a little lost as to how to do it for other values of `n`.

[Three circles within a larger circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666491/three-circles-within-a-larger-circle)

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle

Comment: Thank you @Jens! I see that it's more complicated than I was thinking and there might not be an easy equation 

Comment: Take a look at Soddy's relationship (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SoddyCircles.html)